# meep module in spyder5 modulenotfounderror

Tags: python, module, conda, spyder, environment

I create an env of meep.
'$ conda create -n mp -c conda-forge pymeep pymeep-extras'
then
'$ conda activate mp'

I can import meep module in python.

However, I want to use run it in spyder5. But in the env. mp, I have no spyder. I am confused how to use spyder in mp env.

Comment: Seems like you want to connect Spyder with you `mp` env? If that is the case, you also need to install the `spyder-kernels` package in the `mp` and set the new env interpreter as a custom interpreter inside Spyder preferences. For more info about that you can check the Spyder docs FAQ page (https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-spyder) and the Spyder wiki page (https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes I want to connect spyder with mp env. I have installed spyder-kernels. But I have no spyder in that evn. Problem is that, In the activate mp, I cannot install spyder. How do you install spyder in your mp env?

Comment: I found a solution. It's not kernels. I have installed spyder in the env through conda-forge.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the problem and solved it. The solution is quite simple, that is installing meep and spyder at the same time with this command:
conda create -n meep -c conda-forge pymeep pymeep-extras spyder